# Kissing Back of Hand

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, chasidut-hasidism, hands-fingers, kissing

Is there a source for Sephardim and Chassidim that kiss the hand of their Rabbi, a Torah scholar or even their father upon meeting them?

Comment: It sounds to me like an age-old custom....there's the Wiki for "hand kissing" and a Jewish version that has some good stuff:  http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/9354-kiss-and-kissing

Comment: ...and it looks like someone "asked the Rabbi" pretty much the same question, but the sources listed at the bottom don't clarify what part of the tradition they're the source of: http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/155/Q1/

Comment: I'm more curious about the custom of people who kiss the back of their own hand after they touch yours after an aliyah for the Torah.

Comment: @DanF Could it be like kissing your hand after touching the Sefer Torah?

Answer (score 4):

[Kaf Hachaim 262:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14421&st=&pgnum=70) says that there is a Inyan to kiss the hand of a Gadol who wrote Chidushei Torah and to get a Bracha from them.

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud ([Berachos 8b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8b&format=pdf)) mentions kissing the hand:

> תניא אמר ר"ע בשלשה דברים אוהב אני את המדיים כשחותכין את הבשר אין
>   חותכין אלא על גבי השולחן כשנושקין אין נושקין אלא על גב היד וכשיועצין
>   אין יועצין אלא בשדה
>
> It has been taught: R. Akiba says: For three things I like the Medes:
>   When they cut meat, they cut it only on the table; when they kiss,
>   they kiss only the hand; and when they hold counsel, they do so only
>   in the field. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

Rashi there explains:

> על גב היד. את יד חברו הוא נושק ודרך חשיבות הוא זה מפני הרוק

[R. Chaim Vital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayyim_ben_Joseph_Vital) ([Sha'ar HaKavanos, Inyan Arvis Leil Shabbos Derush 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14189&st=&pgnum=68)) explains the mystical power of kissing the hand, especially the hand of someone superior:

> והואיל ואתא לידן נבאר ענין הנשיקה שנוהגים לנשק ע"ג הידים מה ענין זה דע
>   כי הגבו' הם הנקרא מנצפ"ך והם עומדי' ביסוד של הנקבה ואמנם שורש מציאותם
>   הא' הוא בה' אצבען יד שמאלי' כי ה' אצבעות יד ימין הם חסדים ושורש כל
>   הגבורות האלו הוא למעלה בה' מוצאות הפה והם חיך ולשון וגרון ושפה ושינים
>   שבהם כ"ב אותיו' אחע"ה בומ"ף כו' והנה ג' חלוקו' שבהם הם ד' אותיו' והם
>   אחע"ה בומ"ף גיכ"ק וב' חלוקו' שבהם הם ה' אותיו' והם דטלנ"ת זשסר"ץ והס
>   סוד ה' חסדים וה"ג וכאשר האדם נושק בפיו ע"ג אצבעו' היד גורם להשפיע
>   ולהאיר משרש' אשר שם בפה אל הה' אצבעו' ואמנם סדר הנשיקה הוא שהקטן נושק
>   יד הגדול והכוונה היא כיון שהקטן בא להתברך מן הגדול לכן צריך שבתחי'
>   יגרום הקטן ביסוס ומיתוק גבו' הגדול הזה ע"י הנשיקה כנז' ועי"כ מתעורר
>   אח"ך הרחמים של הגדול המברך את הקטן